# how to extract two words from a string using awk?

Tags: bash, awk

I have the below string:

```
70171  32982  0 17:44 pts/5    00:00:00 grep persist
```

Im trying to extract the words "grep" & "persist" from the above string.

I tried using `awk -F' ' '{print $8,$9}'` but that's not giving me the expected result.

Can someone tell me how it can be done using awk command.

Comment: `awk '{print $7,$8}'`?

Comment: OP the `$8` and `$9` represent the position of the field after splitting it with a space `-F' '`. Counting you'll see that `grep` is at position `7` and `persist` is at position `8`. Generally when cutting/splitting `ps -ef` output there is an extra field at the beginning for the username that started the process, your `ps` output string/line doesn't have that so you have to adjust your field positions down by 1.

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Answer (score 2):

`awk` default field separator handle spaces.  If you want to extract the last two fields perhaps

```
$ awk '{print $(NF-1),$NF}' file
```